# How to query an Entity Framework entities container for objects of derived entity classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a complex inheritance structure in my data model. A majority of classes in my model (which is designed in VS 2010 with a DB generated by it after) are derived from 3 basic classes. And only these 3 classes can be found among the context members. How do I use all the derived classes at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query for subtypes like this:

```
  var horses = from animal in ctx.AnimalSet
               where animal is Horse
               select animal as Horse;
```

This will fetch all Horse objects from the Animal set in my examle context.

If you wish to query on sub type specific properties you can do:

```
var horses = from animal in ctx.AnimalSet
             where animal is Horse //edit, this line is not needed
             let horse = animal as Horse
             where horse.TracksWon > 3
             select horse;
```

This will all be translated to SQL, so there is no overhead like fetching all animals and filtering on client side, it works as it should.

HTH

Answer (score 10):

Roger's answer kind of works, but might not give you the results you want. It's generally better to use `OfType()`. To use his examples:

```
var horses = from animal in ctx.AnimalSet
             where animal is Horse
             select animal as Horse;
```

This makes `horses` of type `IQueryable<Animal>`. But in this case you probably want `IQueryable<Horse>`, which you can get by:

```
var horses = from animal in ctx.AnimalSet.OfType<Horse>()
             select animal;
```

... or just:

```
var horses = ctx.AnimalSet.OfType<Horse>();
```

Similarly, Roger's second query can be rewritten as:

```
var horses = from horse in ctx.AnimalSet.OfType<Horse>()
             where horse.TracksWon > 3
             select horse;
```

Which is easier to read, but changes the result type to `IQueryable<Horse>`.